# Try clicking een element after the error: element not visible

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium-chromedriver

I use the code below to click on an element. However, it returns the error: element not visible. When i use a wait of a few seconds, the click works. is there a way i can send the click again after the error is thrown? Like a loop?

```
$searchBtnIris2 = $driver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="menuFormHome:j_id44_body"]/ul[3]/li[1]/a')
Write-Host "Den ID van de zoekknop is $seachBtnIris2"
$searchBtnIris2.Click();
```

Comment: Why don't you wait for the document to be ready before clicking instead of developing error-driven code?

Comment: Is there a way to be sure the element is clickable before actually clicking it?